# Getting error while starting/restarting/stopping docker containers

Tags: linux, docker, centos, containers

I am trying to restart my containers after starting the Virtual machine but getting this error.

> Error response from daemon: container "8982213db3e8b24cb57af9b64b92122068c3f6ccfe8d3ba9da1b90534921fa67": already exists
>   Error: failed to start containers: 8982213db3e8

These containers are stopped and should start.

`docker info` gave the below result.

```
Containers: 6
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 6
Images: 8
Server Version: 18.02.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9b55aab90508bd389d7654c4baf173a981477d55
runc version: 9f9c96235cc97674e935002fc3d78361b696a69e
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 2.829GiB
Name: fcp-17685l.india.rapidigm.com
ID: TA6O:JQW5:QJKA:OWSB:BHR4:ASKM:QNV3:WPPR:GPPS:42BD:A3WC:DRAZ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

What to do??

Comment: What virtual machine are you talking about ? What command do you use to start your container ?

Comment: working on Oracle Virtual Box and installed using "yum install docker-ce".

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a known bug: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36145. It is fixed [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36249). The fix is merged but I can not check if there is already a new version available. If it is you should upgrade. Otherwise downgrading seems like a solution. (or using a workaround which is discussed in the issue).